# R operator overloading

Tags: r, operator-overloading

Does anyone know how to overload the `[]` operator in R?

```
`[]` <- function(a, b) a + b 
x = 5
y = 5
x[]y
Error: unexpected symbol in "x[]y"
```

R operator overloading seems to work for all other symbols except the `[]`and `()`.

Comment: It's just `[` and there are methods, so you'll want (but, do you really?) to override`[.data.frame`.

Comment: ...oh, but if you're just trying to create a user-defined infix operator (which in this case is totally different than overloading `[`) you have to use `%` on either side. So you'd name it something like `%myinfix%` or something.

Comment: overload or overwrite? `[` <- function(x,y) x + y; `[`(2,3)...note that backticks are not showing up in this comment

Comment: Yeah joran's statement works. But I am trying to get create an operator that is just composed of  `[` or `[]`